# Open Graph scraping base URL instead the URL it's given

Tags: facebook, magento, facebook-opengraph

The Facebook OpenGraph debug tool is scraping the wrong page.

If I give it a full URL (pointing to an individual page on my site) that I want it to scrape, instead of scraping that page and finding its meta tags, it scrapes my site's *main page* and returns those meta tags (which are obviously wrong in this context).

The weird thing is, it will even find and scrape my site's main page even if it's not located at the root of my domain.  For example:
I want it to scrape `http://mydomain.com/myhomepage/specific_page.html`
Instead, it scrapes `http://mydomain.com/myhomepage/`

This implies to me that the error must be a setting someplace, either on my site or on my Facebook App settings.  Would the App settings do that?  Redirect to whatever URL is set if a requested URL is a descendent of it?
The URL I'm requesting is not doing a 302 or anything - I can click the link from the FB debug tool even and it will take me to the appropriate page.

A few notes:

- `specific_page.html` is not an actual file, it is routed through index.php using mod_rewrite in Apache's htaccess.  I tried being specific with `http://mydomain.com/myhomepage/index.php/specific_page.html` and it did not work then either.
- Another SO question led me to believe that the user-agent might be getting redirected if it doesn't allow cookies (as the Facebook web crawler does not) so I opened a fresh browser, disabled cookies, tried again, and I still reached the appropriate page.

Comment: Most likely problems here: 1) you're returning a HTTP redirect to facebook's crawler, sending it to the root URL instead of the URL which was requested. 2) you have an og:url meta tag on specific_page.html pointing to the site root
3) you have a canonical ref meta tag pointing to the site root

Comment: Thank you for such a concise list of possibilities!  That made it substantially easier to iterate.  It was (2), an og:url tag was pointing to the site root instead of the current site.  It was getting its value from a call to `$this->getCurrentUrl()`, so you can understand that I might have overlooked it :)  
Would you care to transfer your suggestions into an answer, that I may award you by accepting it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, in your case this was due to an `og:url` meta tag, redirecting Facebook's crawler to that URL

In general, cases like this are usually the `og:url` tag, a HTTP redirect, or a canonical meta tag pointing at the 'other' / 'wrong' URL - Facebook's crawler follows those redirects looking for the final URL

Comment: Thanks!!  This was really killing me for a while.

Comment: Hi! How did this help you? I mean, what did you do to make it NOT redirect you? Thanks.

Comment: @Desprit The problem (in my case) was that the page I was _trying_ to scrape (e.g. `http://example.com/myhomepage/specific_page.html`) included an `og:url` tag whose value pointed to a different page (e.g. `http://example.com/myhomepage/`).  When Facebook's crawler sees that `og:url` tag, it scrapes the URL specified within it instead of the URL you gave it.  You just have to either remove the `og:url` tag or set its value to the _current_ page URL instead.

Comment: @Desprit for me, I had og:url set to the base url, so facebook thumbnails were of the *base* url's meta attributes, rather than those specified for the particular page  (basically it was ignoring all the meta info I had set, because I had accidentally set og:url to the root/base url).